# Add mean to secondary box in primary boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, boxplot

I'm very new to R so my apologies in advance for the stupid question. I've tried to find the answer to that one extensively before coming here but was unsuccessful...
The `stat_summary (fun.y=mean)` works for the primary boxes but not for the others. Any idea how I could add the same to the `stat_boxplot` ones (colored boxes on on the right; different data set)?

```
ggboxplot(dat, x = "SW.group", 
               y = "lysc", 
               width = 0.25, 
               xlab = FALSE,
               ylim = c(-100,400), 
               ylab= FALSE, border = "black") + 
stat_boxplot(data = dat1, 
             size = 0.5, 
             width = 0.25, 
             aes(color = SW), 
             position = position_nudge(x = 0.3)) +  
scale_colour_manual(name = "",  
                    values = c("Sargassum" = "orangered4", 
                               "Ulva" = "green4", 
                               "Gracilaria" = "red"), 
                    labels = c("Sargassum\n(n = 35)", 
                                "Ulva\n(n = 11)", 
                                "Gracilaria\n(n = 13)")) + 
scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Brown\n(n = 108)", 
                            "Green\n(n = 31)", 
                             "Red\n(n = 30)")) + 
theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 12)) + 
stat_summary(fun.y = "mean",
             shape = 4,
             col = 'black',
             geom = 'point')
```

Thanks in advance!

[image: boxplot]

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's hard to help you without it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding another `stat_summary` layer and point it to the second data set using `data = dat1`.

Comment: I thought I had tried that but I must have done it incorrectly before but it worked! I just needed to add:
 "+ stat_summary(data = dat1, fun.y=mean,shape=4,col='black',geom='point', position = position_nudge(x = 0.3))"
Thanks a lot Arienrhod